# Generate configmap using Kustomization, but the name in `configMapRef` doesn't include the suffix

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kustomize

The project structure of my k8s YAML manifests with kustomization is like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── base
│   │   └── kustomization.yaml
|   |   └── my-configmap.yaml
|   |   └── my-deploy.yaml  
|   |   └── my-svc.yaml  
│   ├── overlay
│       └── kustomization.yaml
```

In **base's** *kustomization.yaml*:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - my-configmap.yml
  - my-deploy.yml
  - my-svc.yml
configMapGenerator:
  - name: db
    literals:
      - SQLITE_DB_LOCATION=/tmp/db/my.db
```

As you can see above, I have declared `configMapGenerator` with name `db`.

In **base's** *my-deploy.yaml* :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deploy
  namespace: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: foo123/my-app:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: my-configmap
        - configMapRef:
            name: db   # I refer to the generator's ConfigMap here!
```

As you can see above, under container's `envFrom`, I have two `configMapRef`, the 2nd one refers to name `db`.

Under `app/base/` directory, I build kustomization with command `kustomize build . | cat`, the output YAML shows me:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  SQLITE_DB_LOCATION: /tmp/db/my.db
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db-mmm78m6dgk  # The generated ConfigMap has suffix in name, that is kustomize's default behaviour.
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-deploy
  namespace: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: sp-oauth-config
        - configMapRef:
            name: db  # I wished Kustomize will use name `db-mmm78m6dgk` here, but it doesn't...
```

As you can see above built output, the **ConfigMap** generated by kustomization is named `db-mmm78m6dgk`, I fully understand that kustomization by default append suffix to the name.

But I also expect kustomization is able to automatically use the same name when referring the **ConfigMap** in container's `configMapRef` field, however, the above output shows me the final referred name is `db`.  WHY?

Why kustomization doesn't use `db-mmm78m6dgk` for container's `configMapRef` field but `db`??

---

I installed standalone Kustomize tool, version `v5.2.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the `namespace: my-app` metadata in the Deployment. Remove it and it should be fine :)

I don't know why having the namespace is a problem tbh, I went through the same thing a couple of months ago and I found [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/554#issuecomment-446300952) that helped me. You can still specify the `namespace` inside your `kustomization.yaml`.